# Download .xap file in local storage and install it programatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to put upgrade functionality in my application. New application should be downloaded from my personal server. After completion of download. It should automatically install.

Please suggest me

Comment: Hi Zakir, wanted to know if you got answer for this question, I am looking for the same functionality. Can we programmatically install .xap file? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Impossible in Windows Phone for security reasons. That behavior is very "Androidish" (DexClassLoader).

The only ways to install a .xap in Windows Phone are through the Store, the SD card (but only if the same .xap is present in the store & hashes are the same) and by having your phone "Developer Unlocked" and using the "Application deployment tool" from your computer.

Mark as an answer if it answered your question.